# Schoolteaching Research and Academia

Tags: phd, supervision, academic-life, research-topic, networking

I am struggling getting research interest in a suite of schoolteaching research topics. I feel that many of my topics should not threatening and should be of interest to schoolteachers and schoolteaching lecturers. One is looking at the use of letter tracing when learbing writing and the other looking at integrating misconceptions in teaching.

However I am getting a lot of hostility and discouragement from university lecturers. I have emailed many lecturers at my institution and some outside but without success.

I am used to academics referring me to others rather than discourage and not progress the debate. It seems very unacademic and uncollegial. I am not sure what I can differently or whether you all have more context and strategies that I can try. I would like help in what else I can do please?

I feel very passionately about my schoolteaching research interest. If we improve schoolteaching and support schoolteachers more we can make a huge difference...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Is education research your primary field? What is it that you want these university lecturers to do for you?

Comment: Ideally I would love to do a phd. But I have two papers under review on my own. So I can go the independent research route of needed...

Comment: Whose interest are you trying to capture? What are you wanting them to do, that they don't want to do? Why "hostility"? Etc. If you're wanting advice, I think you're being too vague about the "problem to be solved"...

Comment: I am not keen to drill down into topics because the details are confusing.

Comment: One topic is on the issue of tracing letters and words in very early handwriting learning. The other topic is integrating common misconceptions in the teaching of maths broadly through a case example.

Comment: Is it "College of Education" faculty you're trying to engage? And what do you want them to do that they are "hostile" about?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not contain a question.

Comment: I have emailed lecturers and researchers in my research interest without success.

Comment: Are you trying to recruit these people to be your participants? Or asking them for research advice?

Comment: Sorry, research advice

Comment: I already have supportive large facebook groups that are willing participants

Comment: @Poidah Well, since no one else is giving you advice, I'll give you one piece: **MAKE SURE YOU HAVE HUMAN SUBJECTS RESEARCH APPROVAL BEFORE STARTING HUMAN SUBJECTS RESEARCH**. Given your independence, you may have missed that step. If you're not in the US, rules may differ from the ones I am familiar with, but importantly note that it may not be up to you to decide if your research is "exempt" or otherwise less regulated than other research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are an early-career independent researcher looking for research mentorship.

The ordinary way that people get this research mentorship is by joining a degree program - a masters program with a research component, or ideally a PhD. Undergraduates can also look into opportunities for research mentorship. Advising a new researcher is a *lot* of work; it's quite reasonable to expect the trade off of time invested versus research output to be negative over the first couple (or even several) years: that is, an experienced advisor would be more productive if they spent their time on research rather than training. However, advisors have a responsibility to mentor their students in these programs, both to their employer institution and to academia as a whole.

If you cold-email people asking for their advice on your research project, you're going outside this system. Would you cold-email professional sports coaches to help you practice your athletic skills and expect a response? Certainly not; probably not even if you have extreme athletic promise! They'll have a system of lower-level coaches and scouts who seek out those sorts of athletes. Even if you offered a good sum of money, their schedule and contractual obligations likely prevent them from even considering the offer.

I don't think the rejections you are getting are based on the quality or importance of your research project, you're just asking the wrong people for the wrong thing. If you want to research and learn to do research, apply for training programs in research. You mention you can try an independent route...I would very strongly discourage that. Research is very difficult and you'll get stuck a lot. You need a mentor who can help you through those spots, and slowly build your skills to work through these problems on your own in the future.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. It is different in Australia

Comment: Usually one can informally email potential supervisors and then formally apply to the institution for a program.

Comment: I did say that I am interested in a PhD and usually that would lead to suggestions of potential supervisors to approach. That has not been the case so far.

Comment: @Poidah Your question didn't say you were interested in a PhD, just that you've been emailing your research project around.

Comment: Yes in my previous discipline, research discussion happens a lot more and then if there is a good working relationship then a PhD forms. Sorry if I was too vague. Thanks for your help Bryan